# After fetching UITableView Section and Row... what does this code do?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

Can anyone explain me what this code does after getting NSArray....

```
- (UIViewController *)sampleForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *samples = [samples_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Class clazz = [samples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIViewController *instance = [[clazz alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    return [instance autorelease];
  }
```

I am getting NSArray of Section... then how can we assign the values of the row to a Class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the array **samples** contains the objects of type **Class**. You can create an instance of class directly using a class name or by using a *Class* object/variable. For example,

```
/* One Way */

// Create an instance of MyViewController deirectly
UIViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

/* Another Way */

// The following line returns a class object
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"MyViewController");
// The below is just for an example. This also returns a class object 
Class cls = [MyViewController class]; 
// Create an instance of MyViewController from the class object
UIViewController *vc = [[cls alloc] init];
```

**Your code uses the second way** to allocate the view controller object from the class object returned by *[samples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]*.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the array, it retrieves a particular `Class` using :

`Class clazz = [samples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

and then it instantiates a `UIViewController` object using the class, and return that object :

```
UIViewController *instance = [[clazz alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
return [instance autorelease];
```